# C# linq expression not pulling the data correctly

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to query two tables and need to pull related records from both the tables. I am using enityframeworkcore 3 One is system versioned table and the other is history table. My resultset is containing data only from history table and not system-versioned table. Could somebody tell me what is wrong with my statement . I am ensured that the personid in the systemversion table matches the history table.

[image]

Query

```
  var personNotes = (from pn in _context.PersonNotes
                              join pnh in _context.PersonNotesHistory on pn.PersonId equals pnh.PersonId
                              select pn);
            return personNotes;
```

Comment: `select pn`  You're telling it to select only from `_context.PersonNotes`.  If you want your LINQ query to produce data from the join, you need to tell it to do that.  What is your expected result for `personNotes`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the column names you want to return in the result:

```
var personNotes = (from pn in _context.PersonNotes
                              join pnh in _context.PersonNotesHistory on pn.PersonId equals pnh.PersonId
                              select new {
                                           data1 = pn.column1,
                                           data2 = pn.column2,
                                           data3 = pn.column3,
                                           data4 = pnh.column1,
                                           data5 = pnh.column2,
                                           data6 = pnh.column3,


                                          }).ToList();
            return personNotes;
```

Just change the `column1, column2, column3` with column names you want to retrieve from the database.

Comment: I am getting a compilation error saying duplicate. I also need to senfd of type PersonNote so trying something like this but have the same duplicate anonymous type error

Comment: var personNotes = (from pn in _context.PersonNotes
                              join pnh in _context.PersonNotesHistory on pn.PersonId equals pnh.PersonId
                              select new PersonNote
                              {
                                 AuthorId  = pn.AuthorId,
                                 Created   = pn.Created,
                                 Note = pn.Note
                                  // pnh.AuthorId,
                                  // pnh.Created,
                                  // pnh.Note


                              });

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can give another name to the selected columns, instead of data1, data2 ..etc you can choose any other name

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the first answer you may use this syntax:

```
var personNotes = _context.PersonNotes
    .Join(_context.PersonNotesHistory, pn => pn.PersonId, pnh => pnh.PersonId, (pn, pnh) => new
    {
        pn.Note,
        pn.AuthorID,
        pn.CreatedBy,
        pnh.Note,
        pnh.AuthorID,
        pnh.CreatedBy
    })
    .ToList();
```